# Comparing CPU utilization during MPI thread deadlock using mvapich2 vs. openmpi

Tags: c, mpi, deadlock, openmpi, mvapich2

I noticed that when I have a deadlocked MPI program, e.g. `wait.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int taskID = -1; 
    int NTasks = -1; 
    int a = 11; 
    int b = 22; 
    MPI_Status Stat;

    /* MPI Initializations */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskID);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NTasks);

    if(taskID == 0)
        MPI_Send(&a, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 66, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else //if(taskID == 1)
        MPI_Recv(&b, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 66, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);

    printf("Task %i :    a: %i    b: %i\n", taskID, a, b); 

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile `wait.c` with the mvapich2-2.1 library (which itself was compiled using gcc-4.9.2) and run it (e.g. `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`) I notice (via `top`), that all 4 processors are chugging along at 100%.

When I compile `wait.c` with the openmpi-1.6 library (which itself was compiled using gcc-4.9.2) and run it (e.g. `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`), I notice (via `top`), that 2 processors are chugging at 100% and 2 at 0%.

Presumably the 2 at 0% are the ones that completed communication.

QUESTION : Why is there a difference in CPU usage between openmpi and mvapich2?  Is this the expected behavior? When the CPU usage is 100%, is that from constantly checking to see if a message is being sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both implementations [busy-wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) on `MPI_Recv()` in order to minimize latencies. This explains why ranks 2 and 3 are at 100% with either of the two MPI implementations.

Now, clearly ranks 0 and 1 progress to the `MPI_Finalize()` call and this is where the two implementations differ: mvapich2 busy-wait while openmpi does not.

To answer your question: yes, they are at 100% while checking whether a message has been received and it is expected behaviour.

If you are not on InfiniBand, you can observe this by attaching a `strace` to one of the processes: you should see a number of poll() invocations there.

Comment: This is discussed further : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560714/probe-seems-to-consume-the-cpu